# PyQGIS attributes weird format

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I need to export layer features to csv file. I import csv and pyqgis lib.

When I get attribute for each feature I have weird format for each feature.attributes():

```
[32L, u'value_001', u'value_002', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3496L, u'value_003', u'value_004']
```

Could you explain me why "32" integer value is return as "32L" by feature.attributes()  ?

This is my code :

```
layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer = layer[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()
attributes= [el.attributes() for el in features]
```

QGISv 2.14.2 ESSEN -> use python 2.7

Comment: This is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) where in Python < 3, integer values given the suffix `L` was used to indicate they were **long integers**. If you check the field, it will probably be of a `qlonglong` type.

Comment: Thank you Joseph ! Do you know way to do not display "L" suffix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) where in Python < 3, integer values given the suffix `L` was used to indicate they were long-type integers. One way to remedy this is to use `int(x)`.

---

Since you're creating a list within a list with `attributes= [el.attributes() for el in features]`, you could try the following which loops through each list and converts each long integer into a *normal* integer and stores the result in a new list:

```
layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer = layers[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()
attributes = [el.attributes() for el in features]
final_attributes = []
for x in attributes:
    final_attributes.append([int(y) if isinstance(y, (long)) else y for y in x])
```

Comment: Of course int() ! This possibility had not crossed my mind... Thank you a lot !

Comment: @Gaet - Most welcome! Glad it was helpful :)